# A few itemssource of Datagrid with are changing with a buttons

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to change the itemsource of datagrid with a 3 buttons. The problem is that the everyone itemsource must have a different datagrid.column definitions. I was trying DataTrigger and MultiDataTrigger but it failed. Is it possible to changing itemsource of datagrid with a 3 independent buttons where each itemsouce have different Datagrid.Column definition? :)

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="lista"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  ColumnWidth="auto"
                  FontFamily="Calibri Light"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  FontSize="16"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="Aqua"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            
                <DataGrid.Columns>                    
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Imię Nazwisko | Nazwa" Binding="{Binding Path=ImieNazwiskoNazwa}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ulica Numer" Binding="{Binding Path=UlicaNumer}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Miasto" Binding="{Binding Path=Miasto}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kod Pocztowy" Binding="{Binding Path=KodPocztowy}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kraj" Binding="{Binding Path=Kraj}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Uwagi" Binding="{Binding Path=Uwagi}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>                
        </DataGrid>
```

C#:

```
private void wyslaneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {     
        lista.ItemsSource = wyslane;
    }

    private void kontaktyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lista.ItemsSource = klienci;
    }

    private void odebraneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lista.ItemsSource = odebrane;
    }
```

I solved this problem but a solution is very primitive. This should be set in XAML code.

C#:

```
 private void kontaktyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        //FIRST BUTTON
        KontaktyData();
        lista.ItemsSource = klienci;
    }
    private void wyslaneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   
        //SECOUND BUTTON
        WyslaneData();
        lista.ItemsSource = wyslane;            
    }

    private void odebraneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //THIRD BUTTON
        OdebraneData();        
        lista.ItemsSource = odebrane;
    }

    private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void OdebraneData()
    {
        //ITEMS WHITH ARE CHANGING WHEN THIRD BUTTON CLICK
        PrintButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        lista.Columns.Clear();

        Style columnStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center));

        DataGridTextColumn data = new DataGridTextColumn();
        data.Header = "Data";            
        data.Binding = new Binding("Data");
        data.Binding.StringFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm";
        data.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(data);

        DataGridTextColumn nadawca = new DataGridTextColumn();
        nadawca.Header = "Nadawca";
        nadawca.Binding = new Binding("Klient.ImieNazwiskoNazwa");
        nadawca.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(nadawca);

        DataGridTextColumn odbiorca = new DataGridTextColumn();
        odbiorca.Header = "Odbiorca";
        odbiorca.Binding = new Binding("Klient1.ImieNazwiskoNazwa");
        odbiorca.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(odbiorca);

        DataGridTextColumn tresc = new DataGridTextColumn();
        tresc.Header = "Treść";
        tresc.Binding = new Binding("Tresc");     
        tresc.Width = 300;
        tresc.ElementStyle = columnStyle;                    
        lista.Columns.Add(tresc);

        DataGridTextColumn osobaOdbierajaca = new DataGridTextColumn();
        osobaOdbierajaca.Header = "Osoba Odbierająca";
        osobaOdbierajaca.Binding = new Binding("OsobaOdbierajacaID");
        osobaOdbierajaca.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(osobaOdbierajaca);

        DataGridTextColumn uwagi = new DataGridTextColumn();
        uwagi.Header = "Uwagi";
        uwagi.Binding = new Binding("Uwagi");
        uwagi.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(uwagi);

        DataGridTextColumn zalacznik = new DataGridTextColumn();
        zalacznik.Header = "Załącznik";
        zalacznik.Binding = new Binding("Zalacznik");
        zalacznik.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(zalacznik);
    }
    private void WyslaneData()
    {
        //ITEMS WHITH ARE CHANGING WHEN SECOUND BUTTON CLICK
        PrintButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        lista.Columns.Clear();

        Style columnStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center));


        DataGridTextColumn data = new DataGridTextColumn();
        data.Header = "Data";
        data.Binding = new Binding("Data");
        data.Binding.StringFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm";
        data.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(data);

        DataGridTextColumn nadawca = new DataGridTextColumn();
        nadawca.Header = "Nadawca";
        nadawca.Binding = new Binding("Klient.ImieNazwiskoNazwa");
        nadawca.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(nadawca);

        DataGridTextColumn odbiorca = new DataGridTextColumn();
        odbiorca.Header = "Odbiorca";
        odbiorca.Binding = new Binding("Klient1.ImieNazwiskoNazwa");
        odbiorca.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(odbiorca);

        DataGridTextColumn tresc = new DataGridTextColumn();
        tresc.Header = "Treść";
        tresc.Binding = new Binding("Tresc");
        tresc.MaxWidth = 300;
        tresc.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(tresc);

        DataGridTextColumn osobaWysylajaca = new DataGridTextColumn();
        osobaWysylajaca.Header = "Osoba Wysyłająca";

        Binding binding = new Binding("Pracownik.Imie");
        Binding binding2 = new Binding("Pracownik.Nazwisko");

        MultiBinding multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(binding);
        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(binding2);
        multiBinding.Converter = new MultiValueConverter();

        osobaWysylajaca.Binding = multiBinding;

        osobaWysylajaca.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(osobaWysylajaca);


        DataGridCheckBoxColumn potwierdzenieWyslania = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
        potwierdzenieWyslania.Header = "Potwierdzenie Wysłania";
        potwierdzenieWyslania.Binding = new Binding("PotwierdzenieWyslania");
        lista.Columns.Add(potwierdzenieWyslania);

        DataGridTextColumn uwagi = new DataGridTextColumn();
        uwagi.Header = "Uwagi";
        uwagi.Binding = new Binding("Uwagi");
        uwagi.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(uwagi);

        DataGridTextColumn zalacznik = new DataGridTextColumn();
        zalacznik.Header = "Załącznik";
        zalacznik.Binding = new Binding("Zalacznik");
        zalacznik.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(zalacznik);
    }
    private void KontaktyData()
    {
        //ITEMS WHITH ARE CHANGING WHEN FIRST BUTTON CLICK
        PrintButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        lista.Columns.Clear();

        Style columnStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
        columnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center));

        DataGridTextColumn imieNazwiskoNazwa = new DataGridTextColumn();
        imieNazwiskoNazwa.Header = "Imię Nazwisko | Nazwa";
        imieNazwiskoNazwa.Binding = new Binding("ImieNazwiskoNazwa");
        imieNazwiskoNazwa.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(imieNazwiskoNazwa);

        DataGridTextColumn ulicaNumer = new DataGridTextColumn();
        ulicaNumer.Header = "Ulica i Numer";
        ulicaNumer.Binding = new Binding("UlicaNumer");
        ulicaNumer.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(ulicaNumer);

        DataGridTextColumn miasto = new DataGridTextColumn();
        miasto.Header = "Miasto";
        miasto.Binding = new Binding("Miasto");
        miasto.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(miasto);

        DataGridTextColumn kodPocztowy = new DataGridTextColumn();
        kodPocztowy.Header = "Kod Pocztowy";
        kodPocztowy.Binding = new Binding("KodPocztowy");
        kodPocztowy.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(kodPocztowy);

        DataGridTextColumn kraj = new DataGridTextColumn();
        kraj.Header = "Kraj";
        kraj.Binding = new Binding("Kraj");
        kraj.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(kraj);

        DataGridTextColumn uwagi = new DataGridTextColumn();
        uwagi.Header = "Uwagi";
        uwagi.Binding = new Binding("Uwagi");
        uwagi.ElementStyle = columnStyle;
        lista.Columns.Add(uwagi);            
    }
```

Comment: One way would be to change your model's properties and switch auto generation on. Then Data Grid would adjust to columns you need. By that I mean, have your model expose properties you want as columns as public. It is all read only anyway.

Comment: Yes, when auto generation is ON then all works fine. The problem is that auto generation display a few columns whith i dont want to display. I solved this problem using only C# as you can see above but this solution isnt good. i would like to do it in XAML :( The problem is how change datagrid.columns in xaml with buttons.

Comment: You can also solve it by changing properties to private or protected. No C# changes needed then

Comment: Hmm i dont know what you mean :/

Comment: I meant create a model to have only public properties that you want to show (one per each variants that you need). Then you don't need to do all of this malarkey about changing columns in code behind.